# Can I write `sin(whatever)`?

Tags: java

Can i write `sin(whatever)` in Java and have it work?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        double check = Double.parseDouble(args[0]);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.exit(0);
    }
    sin(args[0]);
}
```

Comment: Why don't you try it?

Comment: @skaffman +1 Always good to try it first. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running anything below Java 1.5, no. If you aren't, you can, using [static imports](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html); you can write `import static java.lang.Math.*;` and then `sin(whatever);` and this is OK. Be aware of the warning from Sun, though:

> Q: So when should you use static imports?
>
> A: **Very Sparingly!**

If you happen to be running something below Java 1.5, you can still write `sin(whatever)`, but this method must be present...

```
public static double sin(double x) { Math.sin(x); }
```

Answer (score 4):

No it won't, you have to call `sin` with a number like this:

```
sin(Double.parseDouble(args[0]));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can either import it statically from Math package or use the syntax

```
y = Math.sin(x);
```

with doubles `x` and `y`.

In your case `x` can be e.g. `check` but have to declare it outside the block.

Answer (score 2):

no you have to pass in a double or something that can be implicitly converted to a double (no objects or Strings)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double check;
    try {
        check = Double.parseDouble(args[0]);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.exit(0);
    }
    System.out.println(Math.sin(check));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to?  For example if your arg is "I wandered lonely as a cloud", what is the meaning of `sin()` of it?  Check your input - that's a basic tenet of programming.